Copying Content DB from Production to Non-Production on sites with Add-ins
We are using SharePoint 2013 on premises. We host an add-in locally. We occasionally need to copy a production content DB back to a non-production farm. When the site is brought up the add-ins don't work. Currently it is a manual process to upgrade them to the local add-in.
Once the site is backup I delete the instance of the app in site contents. This removes them from the pages. I then open each page and add back the app and configure the webpart.
I've not seen where this has been done using PowerShell. Is it a purely manual process? One site isn't bad but 200+ sites is gonna ruin my weekend.
